# Boxplot and columns combined in a single chart with Highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to use Highcharts.js to create a chart made up of two types: a box plot and a column inside the same cartesian axis system.
 
I've got two y axes with different scales (the one for the box plot data on the left and the one for the columns on the right).
 
The series share the same categories on the x-axes.
Can I combine this two rapresentations in the same chart? The results should be something like this: [Boxplot combined with Columns example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3u5g2xqw7ub39c2/boxplot_column_example.png?dl=0).

Comment: Yep, just use 'type' attribute for each series. So the type for one series would be column and the other would be boxplot.

Comment: Yes, but why? If they need to separate y axes, they don't make sense on the same plot, and should be plotted separately. Anything else is begging for misinterpretation of the data. FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

You could use both series types without any problems. To set each point of boxplot series on left side of each column you could use `pointPadding` and `pointGroupping` for columns and `pointPlacement` for boxplot.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zyy2g6xs/